# PHP page loads a program on the local box silently

Tags: php

I have a page that is used to restart an EXE on a local Windows Box. Essentially someone browses to the page, logs in, then they can restart an certain process I have defined. After the page has checked their session is valid it runs a taskkill on the local Windows box for the correct process then restarts the process with parameters.

Everything works great except on start of the new process it runs silently. Normally running `program.exe -arguments -arguments` from CMD loads a small console window with information. When I have PHP load it with either shell_exec or exec it loads perfectly fine except the console window does not appear. I have even created a batch file and tried calling the batch file with and without START in both exec and shell_exec to start `program.exe -arguments -arguments` and I still get no console window.

Here's the batch file that did not work:

```
@ECHO OFF
START C:\program.exe -arguments -arguments
EXIT
```

AND

```
@ECHO OFF
C:\program.exe -arguments -arguments
EXIT
```

Comment: Hello Miken,Do you know of anyway to have it run as a certain user? I saw some example for Linux with PHP calling the items as the specified user but since this is Windows it is different.

Answer (score -1):

The arguments are not passed to the executable because you aren't enclosing the file and path name in double quotes.

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
START "C:\program.exe" -arguments -arguments
EXIT
```

Comment: Just tried with that, the program still started silently. I did have to remove the START in front of it otherwise it gave an error.

Comment: Did the console window appear after you removed the START?

Comment: Hello Jordy,It did not.